# Converting char into int in C (Credit in cs50)

Tags: c, cs50

I just got into C programming and learning in CS50. I was trying to convert the `char` generated from the card number into an integer that I can sum with. Basically, I'm looking for an equivalent for Java's `charAt()` in C.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){

    int byTwo = 0;

    int byOne = 0;

    int sum = 0;

    string cardNumber = get_string("Card number: ");//from cs50 library

    for (int i = strlen(cardNumber)-2 ; i>0 ; i-=2)
    {
        byTwo += atoi(cardNumber[i])*2;//this is where the problem is
    }
    for (int i = strlen(cardNumber)-1 ; i>0 ; i-=2)
    {
        byOne += atoi(cardNumber[i]);//and here
    }

    sum = byTwo + byOne;

    printf("the sum is: %d " , (int)cardNumber);
    }
```

**Two compiler errors are generated:**

```
clang -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow    credit.c  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o credit
credit.c:18:23: error: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter of type 'const char *'; take the address with & [-Werror,-Wint-conversion]
        byTwo += atoi(cardNumber[i])*2;
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                      &
/usr/include/stdlib.h:104:30: note: passing argument to parameter '__nptr' here
extern int atoi (const char *__nptr)
                             ^
credit.c:22:23: error: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter of type 'const char *'; take the address with & [-Werror,-Wint-conversion]
        byOne += atoi(cardNumber[i]);//and here
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                      &
/usr/include/stdlib.h:104:30: note: passing argument to parameter '__nptr' here
extern int atoi (const char *__nptr)
                             ^
2 errors generated.
```

EDIT:

I fixed the issues and updated the formatting, the code in the question was very makeshift, I apologize. But here's the code I refined on top of the question with 100% cs50 specification: https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2021/psets/1/credit/.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
int byTwo = 0;

int byOne = 0;

int sum = 0;

//getting the card number as long integer and converting into string for easier manipulation
long number = get_long("Card number: ");
char cardNumber[256];
sprintf(cardNumber, "%ld", number);

//loops for luch's algorithm to determine the validity of the card numerically
for (int i = strlen(cardNumber) - 2 ; i >= 0 ; i -= 2)
{
    int fixed = (cardNumber[i] - '0') * 2;//issue fixed here using the accepted method

    if (fixed / 10 >= 1)
    {
        fixed = 1 + fixed % 10;
    }

    byTwo += fixed;
}

for (int i = strlen(cardNumber) - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i -= 2)
{

    byOne += (cardNumber[i] - '0');//issue also fixed here

}

sum = byTwo + byOne;

//guarding statement determining the validity of the card and the providers
if (sum % 10 != 0)
{
    printf("INVALID\n");
}
else if (sum % 10 == 0 && strlen(cardNumber) == 15 && cardNumber[0] == '3' && (cardNumber[1] == '4' || cardNumber[1] == '7'))
{
    printf("AMEX\n");
}
else if (sum % 10 == 0 && strlen(cardNumber) == 16 && cardNumber[0] == '5' && (cardNumber[1] == '1' || cardNumber[1] == '2'
         || cardNumber[1] == '3' || cardNumber[1] == '4' || cardNumber[1] == '5'))
{
    printf("MASTERCARD\n");
}
else if (sum % 10 == 0 && (strlen(cardNumber) == 13 || strlen(cardNumber) == 16) && cardNumber[0] == '4')
{
    printf("VISA\n");
}
else
{
    printf("INVALID\n");
}
}
```

Comment: "*Basically, I'm looking for an equivalent for Java's `charAt()` in C*" - Java's `charAt()` simply returns a `char` at a given index in a `String`.  In C, the `[]` operator does the exact same thing for arrays and strings. The error messages you show are due to you trying to pass a single `char` where a null-terminated `char*` string is expected.

Comment: `printf("the sum is: %d " , (int)cardNumber);` doesn't make much sense. Why not print the variable `sum` while it is printing "the sum is"?

Comment: The function atoi() expects a pointer (like "cardNumber") as an argument. You're trying to pass it a single character. "cardNumber[i]" is the equivalent of Java's charAt(). But you then pass each char into atoi seperately and then add them--I have no idea what you think that's supposed to do. Are you trying to get something like a sum of digits?

Comment: What input do you provide to the program, and what output do you want to get?

Comment: @Austin The code does not make a sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`atoi` is for converting *strings* (sequences of characters terminated by a null-character) to integers, not for converting characters.

To convert decimal characters to corresponding integer, you can subtract `'0'` (the character code for the characer `0` because character code of decimal characters are defined to be continuous in the C specification.

In conculsion, you should replace the two `atoi(cardNumber[i])`s to `(cardNumber[i] - '0')`.